# Java - Converting string into DES key

Tags: java, cryptography, secret-key

I have been given a key as a string and an encrypted file using DES. That is all I know. I don't know how the key was encoded.

There is also a des.exe that I can use to decrypt, this is all I found on the Internet: http://knowledge-republic.com/CRM/2011/07/how-to-decrypt-extract-recreate-thecus-storage-firmware/

Using des.exe, the only command it works with is "-D", not "-d".

My goal is to use Java to do the same thing. I copied and pasted this from somewhere

```
    String key = "blah";
    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    System.out.println(desKey);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for SunJCE

    if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
```

and it doesn't work.

What are some other options in converting a string into a key?

Should probably add I'm a complete newb at cryptography.

Comment: How is the key that you've received encoded?  Is it hex or base64?  You'll have to turn that string into a decoded byte array before passing it off to the DESKeySpec constructor.

Comment: Isn't that what key.getBytes() will do? The key I have is quite literally just a string, I'm not sure what has been done with it. I have tried decoding using Base64 just then and it's complaining that there is an "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data".

Comment: I have tried decoding using UTF8, UTF16, ISO, HEX...nothing. What other ones are there?

Comment: if you mean that you are specifying those values as the "encoding" of the string, don't.  You will need to actually convert the data if it is in hex.

Comment: What length is the key? Which characters does it contain? (Only 0-9 and A-F? Both upper- and lower-case characters? Characters with ASCII values > 127? Control-characters (ASCII values < 20)?

Answer (score 2):

The SunOS man page for [des](http://www.sics.se/man2html/des.1.html) (which seems to be what your des.exe is based on?) indicates that they key is generated like this:

> The DES algorithm requires an 8 byte key whose low order bits are assumed to be odd-parity bits. The ASCII key supplied by the user is zero padded to 8 bytes and the high order bits are set to be odd-parity bits. The DES algorithm then ignores the low bit of each ASCII character, but that bit's information has been preserved in the high bit due to the parity.

It also mentions that the initial IV is always zero'd out, no matter what mode you are running in

> The CBC mode of operation always uses an initial value of all zeros
>   for the initialization vector, so the first 8 bytes of a file are
>   encrypted the same whether in CBC or ECB mode.

It also mentions that the padding used is such that the last byte is always a value from 0-7, indicating the number of padding bytes used.  This is similar to PKCS5Padding, so perhaps that would work

> Since the CBC and ECB modes of DES require units of 8 bytes to be
>   encrypted, files being encrypted by the des command have 1 to 8 bytes
>   appended to them to cause them to be a multiple of 8 bytes. The last
>   byte, when decrypted, gives the number of bytes (0 to 7) which are to
>   be saved of the last 8 bytes. The other bytes of those appended to the
>   input are randomized before encryption.

Based on the options you indicated you are using, it sounds like you are using DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding for the cipher.

I think that just leaves determining how to actually derive the key.  I found this sample code on [exampledepot](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/MakeDes.html) which might work for you.  I think you would just need to convert your string password into 8 bytes (1 byte per character, so no UTF encodings) then stuff it through the code in the example to derive the key.  Its worth a shot anyway.

Comment: yeah, if this is an "exercise" which it sounds like, then that would be pretty meanspirited.  judging from the poorly written documentation for the cited executable it seems like the encryption is either des or 3des in cbc mode.  i'd try testing those ciphers first, before trying to brute force.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested and nope. I tried encrypting/decrypting using "des -E -k "hello", where "hello" is the key and it still works. So if it's one char, one byte then does it fill it up with 0s? It has got be converting it into something else first. @_@ Completely stuck. I think I will have to call this "des.exe" instead of decrypting it myself.

Comment: Yes, the documentation says that it pads the password with 0 bytes to make it a full 8.  If you dont do that, then the key wont be the same and you wont be able to decrypt.  You will also need to make sure you are using a zero'd IV, although that may happen by default (not sure).

Comment: So I've made sure my key is of size 8 bytes, my iv is 0, Cipher is  "DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" and no luck. And I am probably doing something horribly wrong somewhere in the middle @_@. Think I'll just have to call "des.exe" for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

DES keys are 7 (apparently SunJCE uses 7?) or 8 bytes.  Check if the string you have been provided is 7 or 8 bytes.  If so, then the chances are good it's the raw key.  If not, it could be encoded in some fashion.  A giveaway for hex encoding would be a prefix of 0x or suffix of h, and all characters would be in the range 0-9,A-F.  You can certainly convert from hex yourself or use some code on the web, but I usually use an Apache commons lib (http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html).

That said, this is really speculation and I'm not sure we can jump to the conclusion that it's a problem with the key alone.  Do you have any other info on the purported encryption algorithm?  If the executable you cited works with "-d" then it seems like the encryption is plain DES in CBC mode:

> -b         : encrypt using DES in ecb encryption mode, *the defaut is cbc mode*.

(there are multiple possible modes, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA)

I would try setting your cipher to "DES/CBC".

Then again, I'm not sure how to interpret this:

> Default is tripple cbc

You may be able to use this snippet to tell what ciphers are available on your system: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/ListAllProviderAndItsAlgorithms.htm

Comment: I've just decrypted and encrypted using that des.exe and the only command that produces the same result is "-E" and "-D", where only the last few characters are different, using the same key I have been given. The rest give completely different results. :( "-d" doesn't work at all. What do you mean by raw key?

Comment: The key has 8 normal characters, so ... 8 bytes? if it's normal UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with C#. I solved it in the end. You can have a look at my answer here: [DES Initialization Vector in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615252/des-initialization-vector-in-c-sharp/20221027#20221027)

Generally, what des.exe does, is that it computes a checksum using DES. So each encryption step is using the previous result instead of advancing in the output array.